# android: how to visible portion of a view with animation?

Tags: android, animation, translate-animation

I have a invisible `View` behind of another `View`. I want to make this view visible with  a translate animation and show only a part of the right side view.
like this:
[image: sample animation]

I don't want to use 9 patch image and resize that.
this animation named "peek in"" in MS-PowerPoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this

1) create a drawable resource `rectangle_curved.xml` as shown below

```
       <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
        <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
        <corners
            android:bottomRightRadius="350dp"
            android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
            android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
            android:topRightRadius="350dp"/>
        <stroke android:color="#50000000" android:width="2dp"/>
    </shape>
```

2) Set this as the background of the `view` which is expanding and collapsing. Here I have used a `Framelayout` which is expanding and collapsing

```
     <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/shape"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rectangle_curved"/>
```

3) Create a class to handle the expand/collapse animation as follows

```
        public class ResizeAnimation extends Animation {
            private int mWidth;
            private int mInitialWidth;
            private View mView;

            public ResizeAnimation(View view, int width) {
                mView = view;
                mWidth = width;
                mInitialWidth = view.getWidth();
            }

            @Override
            protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
                int newWidth = mInitialWidth + (int) ((mWidth - mInitialWidth) * interpolatedTime);
                mView.getLayoutParams().width = newWidth;
                mView.requestLayout();
            }

            @Override
            public void initialize(int width, int height, int parentWidth, int parentHeight) {
                super.initialize(width, height, parentWidth, parentHeight);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean willChangeBounds() {
                return true;
            }
       }
```

4) Finally, use it like this.  Create a function to handle animation as follows

```
     private void animate(View shapeView, boolean isExpand) {  
        int width = isExpand ? 500 : 0; // 500 is the max width in pixels , you ca change it
        ResizeAnimation anim = new ResizeAnimation(shapeView, width);
        anim.setDuration(500);
        shape.startAnimation(anim);
     }
```

and call this function as follows

for expand animation : `animate(myBackgroundView, true)`

for collapse animation : `animate(myBackgroundView, false)`

EDIT:
in this line of step 4: `int width = isExpand ? 500 : 0;` use 1 instead of 0.
0 not work properly. I don't know why.

```
private void animate(View view, boolean isExpand) {
    int width = isExpand ? 200 : 1; // 200 is the max width in pixels.
    //use a factor for same width on all screen size.
    DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int factor =(int)  metrics.density;
    ResizeAnimation anim = new ResizeAnimation(view, width * factor);
    anim.setDuration(500);
    view.startAnimation(anim);
}
```